# UDP socket in C - recvfrom() doesn't seem to read data from socket as intended

Tags: c, sockets, udp, localserver

I've created an account just for this since I'm at my wits end here:
The goal is for the server to receive and read exactly 2 bytes from the message "Hello from client" - 1 byte at a time with recvfrom().
This doesn't work - the first recvfrom() makes the program sleep indefinitely (I haven't set a timeout in purpose). For the record I am using a Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine with Oracle VM VirtualBox, and I'm fairly new to programming in C.
udp_server.c and udp_client.c codes pasted below, would appreciate any insight.

**udp_server.c:**

```
int main(void) {
    /* Socket */
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket(2)");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Set socket option SO_REUSEADDR */
    int opt = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(2)");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    /* server sockaddr_in struct */
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5061);

    /* Bind */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind(2)");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    /* client sockaddr_in struct (for recvfrom()) */
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));

    /* Receive data from socket */
    fprintf(stdout, "Listening on port %d...\n", 5061);
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    int bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &client_len);
// PROGRAM FREEZES HERE ^^^
    if (bytes_received < 0) {
        printf("bytes_received %d, errno %d", bytes_received, errno);
        perror("recvfrom");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("SUCCESS(1) bytes_received %d", bytes_received);
    bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &client_len);
    if (bytes_received < 0) {
        printf("bytes_received %d, errno %d", bytes_received, errno);
        perror("recvfrom");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("SUCCESS(2) bytes_received %d", bytes_received);

    /* Shutdown */
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

**udp_client.c:**

```
int main(void) {
    /* Socket */
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) { // In case socket creation failed.
        fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: Socket creation failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Server sockaddr_in struct (for sendto()) */
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5061);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("inet_pton(3)");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Send data to socket */
    char* message = "Hello from client";
    int bytes_sent = sendto(sock, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (bytes_sent <= 0) {
        perror("sendto(2)");
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Sent %d bytes to %s:%d - %s\n",
        bytes_sent, inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr), ntohs(server.sin_port), message);
    usleep(75000);

    /* Shutdown */
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my *guess* is that you cannot do that. UDP respects boundary of data send and don't assume that data will be received, so the data may be discarded because it is too large for the reserved buffer.

Comment: You cannot do that with UDP. You have to read the entire message in one go. The bytes you don't read will be lost forever.

Comment: I see, but even so the first recvfrom() should still work properly? Meaning the server should still print "SUCCESS(1) bytes_received ..." no? @n.m.couldbeanAI

Comment: Standard output is probably line-buffered in the server. Try adding newlines (`\n`) to the end of the `printf` strings or calling `fflush(stdout);`. (In particular, the `SUCCESS(1) bytes_received 1` message is probably stuck in the standard output buffer during the second, blocking call to `recvfrom()`.) You can see this if you run the `udp_client` program twice.

Comment: @Jacob No, the client does send only one packet but the server waits for two. Put a success output after the first read and look if `recvfrom` was successful. After that, the server waits for a second packet to arrive, therefore the message output after the second read is never reached (unless another packet is sent to the server).

Answer (score 2):

The `udp_client` program sends a 17-byte datagram to the `udp_server` program, which is expecting two datagrams of 1 byte each. The 16 excess bytes from the first datagram will be discarded.

If the `udp_client` program is run twice, then two 17-byte datagrams will be sent to the `udp_server` program. The 16 excess bytes from each received datagram will be discarded, so `udp_server` will write the following to the standard output stream as a result of reading the two datagrams:

```
Listening on port 5061...
SUCCESS(1) bytes_received 1SUCCESS(2) bytes_received 1
```

Note: there is no newline after the output. The only `printf` call in "udp_server.c" that includes a newline character at the end of the format string is the one that prints the `Listening on port 5061...` message. If the standard output stream is *line buffered*, the output from the other `printf` calls will remain buffered until the program exits, when the buffered contents will be output to the terminal.

For Unix, the usual convention is to initialize the standard input, standard output, and standard error streams as follows:

- For the standard input and standard output streams, if it can be determined that the stream is not connected to a terminal, it will be *fully buffered*, else it will be *line buffered*.
- The standard error stream will be *unbuffered*.

Comment: Standard stream initial buffering is mostly specified by C (e.g. C17 7.21.3/3) not Unix.  Of the details you describe, C fails to specify only whether `stderr` starts line buffered or unbuffered.  However, I think you erred on that point: I haven't checked POSIX, but in my experience, `stderr` defaults to being unbuffered, not line buffered.  Reliably enough so that I was mildly surprised to find that C does not actually specify that.  But this is of course not central to the answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know any standards that specify when streams should start as line buffered or unbuffered, only when streams should not start as fully buffered. After a bit of testing on Linux/Glibc, I think you are correct about `stderr` starting in unbuffered mode and I shall amend my answer accordingly.